# Is the substitution model a good way of approximating how JavaScript evaluates pure code?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, computer-science, lambda-calculus

Say this is my program:

```
let f = x => x * 2
let g = x => f(x) + 1
let h = x => g(x) > 3
h(2)
```

Is the substitution model a good mental model for how the JS runtime evaluates this code, or is the way it's actually evaluated very different?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency

Comment: Depends on *which* JS runtime. Depends on whether the JIT decides to inline the function call. Depends on a lot of things. My *guess* is no: I'm not a systems programmer but mentally walking through how one would write the underlying C++ does not lead me to that implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is evaluated is quite different, though the results will be the same. The most relevant pure CS model to envision is the [environment model](https://xuanji.appspot.com/isicp/3-2-environment.html). In short, when a statement is evaluated, it may mutate the references that it has at that time. These mutations are managed through scope chains in JS, but this is essentially just another name for the environment above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this is exactly what I was looking for. Even though JS evaluates using the environment model, the substitution model will yield the same result for pure functions.

Comment: @bcherny the substitution model does not enforce (or is limited to) a particular evaluation strategy

Answer (score 2):

> Is the substitution model a good way of approximating how JavaScript evaluates pure code?

Of course !

```
let f = x => x * 2
let g = x => f(x) + 1
let h = x => g(x) > 3

h(2)
// = ...
// substitute h with its definition

(x => g(x) > 3) (2)
// substitute x with 2

g(2) > 3
// substitute g with its definition

(x => f(x) + 1) (2) > 3
// substitute x with 2

f(2) + 1 > 3
// substitute f with its definition

(x => x * 2) (2) + 1 > 3
// substitute x with 2

2 * 2 + 1 > 3
// apply * to 2 and 2

4 + 1 > 3
// apply + to 4 and 1

5 > 3
// apply > to 5 and 3

true
```

---

> I understand how to apply the substitution model to my code - my question is how this is different from how real JS runtimes (V8, etc.) evaluate it.

Your question is which [**evaluation strategy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) is JavaScript using – JavaScript uses [*call by sharing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) but of course you can still use the substitution model to arrive at an answer *using* call by sharing evaluation strategy.

The substitution model does not force you to use one strategy over another. In fact, in (almost) all cases, evaluation strategy does not matter if you are using pure functions – the answer will be the same

Comment: I understand *how* to apply the substitution model to my code - my question is how this is different from how real JS runtimes (V8, etc.) evaluate it.

Comment: @bcherny Real implementations compile functions to executable code, and implement function calls as jumps to the compiled code location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!